# Dealing with zero's in a moving average

Tags: python, numpy, average, zero

**EDIT**

My original post was not the best explination, so I have rewritten it.

So what I'm trying to do is calculate the moving average on an array of data. Each average is taken over, for example, the 24 values.
However, I have two conditions that need to be  changed in my current function.

- Take an average over 24 values that ARE NOT zero as zero is considered as bad data, so I want 24 'good' values for the average.
- If there are five **consecutive** zeros, I do not want to take the average and simply say the average is zero.

I need to 
Here is my current function for this, but it needs updating to encompass these changes.

```
def averaged_rel_track(navg, rel_values, nb):
    '''function to average the relative track values for each blade. This is 
    dependant on the number values specified by the user to average over in a 
    rolling average'''
    avg_rel_track=[]
    for blade in range(0,int(nb)):
        av_values=[]
        rel_blade=rel_values[:,int(blade)]
        for rev in range(0,len(rel_blade)):
            section=rel_blade[rev-int(navg)+1:rev+1]
            print section
            if np.any(section==0):   
                av_value=0
            else:
                av_value=np.sum(section)/int(navg)
            print av_value
            av_values.append(av_value)
        avg_rel_track.append(av_values)
    avg_rel_track=np.array(avg_rel_track) 
    return avg_rel_track.transpose()
```

At the moment there is alot of checking involved.

Is there a function where you can select X number of values that are not zero/none? Currently what I'm attempting to do works like this:

```
Select a section of data than is N values long
x= number of zeros/nan's in the data
Extend section by x values
```

But this doesn't work as then I need to check that the new section does not contain zeros and it would detect the original zeros. I could check the extension for zeros, repeating the process, but this seems like a very long winded way to do  this.

I know of `scipy.stats.nanmean` that will ignore the none values when averaging the data.

If anyone could help that would be great, but the main question I would like advice on is:

> Is there a function that will select N values that are not zero or one?

Answer (score 1):

1) can you precise a bit more what you are working on ? what is your set like, what objects you have, what is the type of the container (array, set, ...)

2) you can handle a second "set", that you update with the non zero values you have

3) if 2) is too cumbersome you can always pick a random selection of N * 1.1 objects and try to find N non zero objects in it and repeat, as you suggest. this seems like a fine functionnal algorithm to me too, nothing wrong with that, don't worry

Answer (score 1):

For numpy array:

```
>>> a = np.array([2, 1, 0, np.nan, 0, 5, 6, np.nan, 1, 9, 0, 1, 8, 7, 4])
>>> a[~np.isnan(a) & (a != 0)]
array([ 2.,  1.,  5.,  6.,  1.,  9.,  1.,  8.,  7.,  4.])
>>> a[~np.isnan(a) & (a != 0)][:5]
array([ 2.,  1.,  5.,  6.,  1.])
```

For Python list:

```
>>> import math
>>> a = [2, 1, 0, float('nan'), 0, 5, 6, float('nan'), 1, 9, 0, 1, 8, 7, 4]
>>> [x for x in a if x and not math.isnan(x)]
[2, 1, 5, 6, 1, 9, 1, 8, 7, 4]
>>> [x for x in a if x and not math.isnan(x)][:5]
[2, 1, 5, 6, 1]
```

**NOTE**: Used `if x and not math.isnan(x)` explicitly instead of `if x`, because `nan` is treated as `True` when used as predicate:

```
>>> bool(np.nan)
True
>>> bool(float('nan'))
True
>>> bool(None)
False

>>> float('nan') == float('nan')
False
>>> np.nan == np.nan
False
>>> math.isnan(float('nan')), math.isnan(np.nan)
(True, True)
>>> np.isnan(float('nan')), np.isnan(np.nan)
(True, True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import islice, ifilter
list(islice(ifilter(None, data), 0, N))
```